# DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FabricCommon.dll'

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have created a sample application using service fabric with Docker support. the VS version is 2017 community, Docker community edition version 18.04.0-ce-win62 (17151) and Microsoft Azure service fabric SDK 3.1.269.

I am getting the below error at run time:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'System.Fabric.Common.AppTrace' threw an exception.'
>   Inner Exception : DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FabricCommon.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a mismatch between the SDK version that you're using and the version the cluster is actually running. SDK 3.1 was targeted against runtime 6.2, and it can't run on lower runtimes (think about it - protocols or features may be missing).

TLDR at this point you may have the SDK installed locally, but your cluster probably isn't upgraded to 6.2 yet so you can't deploy things built against that SDK to those clusters until the upgrade happens. This is the normal process.

Supported cluster versions and SDKs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-support#supported-service-fabric-versions). Also you may be running into this since 6.2 was deployed and then pulled back (a new version is going to start rolling out soon). You can find more information about that [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2018/04/19/service-fabric-6-2-release/), [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2018/04/25/update-on-the-service-fabric-6-2-release-roll-out/), and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2018/04/26/second-update-on-the-service-fabric-6-2-release/). I expect there to be more updates when the final build starts rolling out again.

Comment: Hi , Application is working fine when i remove the docker support for the solution.

Comment: Cross verified the versions and I am having SDK 3.1 and cluster version 6.2.

Comment: 1) What API is throwing that exception? 2) How did you verify the cluster version? 3) Are you sure that the runtime is properly installed inside the container then? AFAIK that's not fully supported yet, so it's somewhat unsurprising that there are issues: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-services-inside-containers